# Operações em JPA

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, spring-boot

Bom dia estou desenvolvendo uma aplicação na qual o usuário deve informar ao sistema uma lista de exames e o sistema exibir as unidades laboratoriais que realizam tais exames, porem estou com uma duvida da forma na qual gravar no banco os exames realizados por X unidade todos os outros dados já estão sendo armazenados como devem ser armazenados.

Este é o modelo do diagrama que desenvolvi para a aplicação
[image: Diagrama de Classes]

## Classes de Dominio/Entidades

UnidadeLaboratorio.java

```
package com.moliveiralucas.easylab.domain;

import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.JoinColumn;
import javax.persistence.JoinTable;
import javax.persistence.ManyToMany;
import javax.persistence.ManyToOne;

import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonIgnore;

@Entity
public class UnidadeLaboratorio implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    /* ATRIBUTOS BASICOS */

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Integer id_UnidadeLaboratorio;
    private String nomeUnidade;
    private String logradouro;
    private String complemento;
    private String numero;
    private String telefone;

    /* RELACIONAMENTOS */

    @JsonIgnore
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "id_laboratorio")
    private Laboratorio laboratorio;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "id_cidade")
    private Cidade cidade;

    @JsonIgnore
    @ManyToMany
    @JoinTable(name = "EXAMES_REALIZADOS", joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "id_unidade"), inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "id_exame"))
    private List<Exame> exames = new ArrayList<>();

    /* CONSTRUTORES */

    public UnidadeLaboratorio() {
    }

    public UnidadeLaboratorio(Integer id_UnidadeLaboratorio, String nomeUnidade, String logradouro, String complemento,
        String numero, String telefone, Cidade cidade, Laboratorio laboratorio) {
        super();
        this.id_UnidadeLaboratorio = id_UnidadeLaboratorio;
        this.nomeUnidade = nomeUnidade;
        this.logradouro = logradouro;
        this.complemento = complemento;
        this.numero = numero;
        this.telefone = telefone;
        this.cidade = cidade;
        this.laboratorio = laboratorio;
    }

    /* GETTERS AND SETTERS */

    public Integer getId_UnidadeLaboratorio() {
        return id_UnidadeLaboratorio;
    }

    public void setId_UnidadeLaboratorio(Integer id_UnidadeLaboratorio) {
        this.id_UnidadeLaboratorio = id_UnidadeLaboratorio;
    }

    public String getNomeUnidade() {
        return nomeUnidade;
    }

    public void setNomeUnidade(String nomeUnidade) {
        this.nomeUnidade = nomeUnidade;
    }

    public String getLogradouro() {
        return logradouro;
    }

    public void setLogradouro(String logradouro) {
        this.logradouro = logradouro;
    }

    public String getComplemento() {
        return complemento;
    }

    public void setComplemento(String complemento) {
        this.complemento = complemento;
    }

    public String getNumero() {
        return numero;
    }

    public void setNumero(String numero) {
        this.numero = numero;
    }

    public String getTelefone() {
        return telefone;
    }

    public void setTelefone(String telefone) {
        this.telefone = telefone;
    }

    public Cidade getCidade() {
        return cidade;
    }

    public void setCidade(Cidade cidade) {
        this.cidade = cidade;
    }

    public Laboratorio getLaboratorio() {
        return laboratorio;
    }

    public void setLaboratorio(Laboratorio laboratorio) {
        this.laboratorio = laboratorio;
    }

    public List<Exame> getExames() {
        return exames;
    }

    public void setExames(List<Exame> exames) {
        this.exames = exames;
    }

    /* HASHCODE AND EQUALS */

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        final int prime = 31;
        int result = 1;
        result = prime * result + ((id_UnidadeLaboratorio == null) ? 0 : id_UnidadeLaboratorio.hashCode());
        return result;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        if (this == obj)
            return true;
        if (obj == null)
            return false;
        if (getClass() != obj.getClass())
            return false;
        UnidadeLaboratorio other = (UnidadeLaboratorio) obj;
        if (id_UnidadeLaboratorio == null) {
            if (other.id_UnidadeLaboratorio != null)
                return false;
        } else if (!id_UnidadeLaboratorio.equals(other.id_UnidadeLaboratorio))
            return false;
        return true;
    }

}
```

Exame.java

```
package com.moliveiralucas.easylab.domain;

import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.ManyToMany;

import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonIgnore;

@Entity
public class Exame implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    /* ATRIBUTOS BASICOS */

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Integer id_Exame;
    private String exame;
    private String sigla;

    /* RELACIONAMENTOS */

    @JsonIgnore
    @ManyToMany(mappedBy = "exames")
    private List<UnidadeLaboratorio> unidades = new ArrayList<>();

    /* CONSTRUTORES */
    public Exame() {
    }

    public Exame(Integer id_Exame, String exame, String sigla) {
        super();
        this.id_Exame = id_Exame;
        this.exame = exame;
        this.sigla = sigla;
    }

    /* GETTERS AND SETTERS */

    public Integer getId_Exame() {
        return id_Exame;
    }

    public void setId_Exame(Integer id_Exame) {
        this.id_Exame = id_Exame;
    }

    public String getExame() {
        return exame;
    }

    public void setExame(String exame) {
        this.exame = exame;
    }

    public String getSigla() {
        return sigla;
    }

    public void setSigla(String sigla) {
        this.sigla = sigla;
    }

    public List<UnidadeLaboratorio> getUnidades() {
        return unidades;
    }

    public void setUnidades(List<UnidadeLaboratorio> unidades) {
        this.unidades = unidades;
    }

    /* HASHCODE AND EQUALS */

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        final int prime = 31;
        int result = 1;
        result = prime * result + ((id_Exame == null) ? 0 : id_Exame.hashCode());
        return result;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        if (this == obj)
            return true;
        if (obj == null)
            return false;
        if (getClass() != obj.getClass())
            return false;
        Exame other = (Exame) obj;
        if (id_Exame == null) {
            if (other.id_Exame != null)
                return false;
        } else if (!id_Exame.equals(other.id_Exame))
            return false;
        return true;
    }

}
```

## Classes DTO (Data Transfer Object)

UnidadeLaboratorioDTO.java

```
package com.moliveiralucas.easylab.dto;

import java.io.Serializable;

import javax.validation.constraints.NotEmpty;

import org.hibernate.validator.constraints.Length;

import com.moliveiralucas.easylab.domain.UnidadeLaboratorio;

public class UnidadeLaboratorioDTO implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    private Integer id_UnidadeLaboratorio;
    @NotEmpty(message = "Preenchimento obrigatório")
    @Length(min = 3, max = 50, message = "O campo nomeUnidade deve conter entre 3 e 50 caracteres")
    private String nomeUnidade;
    @NotEmpty(message = "Preenchimento obrigatório")
    @Length(min = 3, max = 50, message = "O campo Logradouro deve conter entre 3 e 50 caracteres")
    private String logradouro;
    @NotEmpty(message = "Preenchimento obrigatório")
    @Length(min = 3, max = 50, message = "O campo Complemento deve conter entre 3 e 50 caracteres")
    private String complemento;
    private String numero;
    private String telefone;

    public UnidadeLaboratorioDTO() {
    }

    public UnidadeLaboratorioDTO(UnidadeLaboratorio obj) {
        id_UnidadeLaboratorio = obj.getId_UnidadeLaboratorio();
        nomeUnidade = obj.getNomeUnidade();
        logradouro = obj.getLogradouro();
        complemento = obj.getComplemento();
        numero = obj.getNumero();
        telefone = obj.getTelefone();
    }

    public Integer getId_UnidadeLaboratorio() {
        return id_UnidadeLaboratorio;
    }

    public void setId_UnidadeLaboratorio(Integer id_UnidadeLaboratorio) {
        this.id_UnidadeLaboratorio = id_UnidadeLaboratorio;
    }

    public String getNomeUnidade() {
        return nomeUnidade;
    }

    public void setNomeUnidade(String nomeUnidade) {
        this.nomeUnidade = nomeUnidade;
    }

    public String getLogradouro() {
        return logradouro;
    }

    public void setLogradouro(String logradouro) {
        this.logradouro = logradouro;
    }

    public String getComplemento() {
        return complemento;
    }

    public void setComplemento(String complemento) {
        this.complemento = complemento;
    }

    public String getNumero() {
        return numero;
    }

    public void setNumero(String numero) {
        this.numero = numero;
    }

    public String getTelefone() {
        return telefone;
    }

    public void setTelefone(String telefone) {
        this.telefone = telefone;
    }

}
```

ExameDTO.java

```
package com.moliveiralucas.easylab.dto;

import java.io.Serializable;

import javax.validation.constraints.NotEmpty;

import org.hibernate.validator.constraints.Length;

import com.moliveiralucas.easylab.domain.Exame;

public class ExameDTO implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    private Integer id_Exame;
    @NotEmpty(message = "Preenchimento obrigatório")
    @Length(min = 3, max = 60, message = "O campo Exame deve ser entre 3 e 60 caracteres")
    private String exame;
    @NotEmpty(message = "Preenchimento obrigatório")
    @Length(min = 2, max = 6, message = "O campo Sigla deve ser entre 3 e 6 caracteres")
    private String sigla;

    public ExameDTO() {
    }

    public ExameDTO(Exame obj) {
        super();
        id_Exame = obj.getId_Exame();
        exame = obj.getExame();
        sigla = obj.getSigla();
    }

    public Integer getId_Exame() {
        return id_Exame;
    }

    public void setId_Exame(Integer id_Exame) {
        this.id_Exame = id_Exame;
    }

    public String getExame() {
        return exame;
    }

    public void setExame(String exame) {
        this.exame = exame;
    }

    public String getSigla() {
        return sigla;
    }

    public void setSigla(String sigla) {
        this.sigla = sigla;
    }

}
```

## Repositorios (JpaRepository)

UnidadeLaboratorioRepository.java

```
    package com.moliveiralucas.easylab.repositories;

    import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository;
    import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;

    import com.moliveiralucas.easylab.domain.UnidadeLaboratorio;

    @Repository
    public interface UnidadeLaboratorioRepository extends JpaRepository<UnidadeLaboratorio, Integer> {

    }
```

ExameRepository.java

```
    package com.moliveiralucas.easylab.repositories;

    import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository;
    import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;

    import com.moliveiralucas.easylab.domain.Exame;

    @Repository
    public interface ExameRepository extends JpaRepository<Exame, Integer> {
        /*
         * @Transactional(readOnly=true)
         * 
         * @Query("SELECT obj FROM exames_realizados obj WHERE obj.exame.id_exame = :exames.exame_id"
         * ) List<Exame> findAllExames(ArrayList<Exame> exames);
         */
    }
```

O trecho comentado na classe ExameRepository.java e pq estourava uma exceção falando que "exames_realizados" não estava mapeado dai fiquei na duvida se eu deveria criar uma classe para mapear esse relacionamento ou ele ja estava sendo mapeado nas classes de dominio.

## Classes RestController

UnidadeLaboratorioResouce.java

```
    package com.moliveiralucas.easylab.resources;

    import java.net.URI;
    import java.util.List;
    import java.util.stream.Collectors;

    import javax.validation.Valid;

    import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
    import org.springframework.data.domain.Page;
    import org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity;
    import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PathVariable;
    import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestBody;
    import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
    import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
    import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestParam;
    import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;
    import org.springframework.web.servlet.support.ServletUriComponentsBuilder;

    import com.moliveiralucas.easylab.domain.UnidadeLaboratorio;
    import com.moliveiralucas.easylab.dto.UnidadeLaboratorioDTO;
    import com.moliveiralucas.easylab.dto.UnidadeLaboratorioNewDTO;
    import com.moliveiralucas.easylab.services.UnidadeLaboratorioService;

    @RestController
    @RequestMapping(value = "/unidadeLaboratorios")
    public class UnidadeLaboratorioResource {

        @Autowired
        private UnidadeLaboratorioService service;

        @RequestMapping(value = "/{id}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
        public ResponseEntity<?> find(@PathVariable Integer id) {
            UnidadeLaboratorio obj = service.find(id);
            return ResponseEntity.ok().body(obj);
        }

        @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET)
        public ResponseEntity<List<UnidadeLaboratorioDTO>> findAll() {
            List<UnidadeLaboratorio> list = service.findAll();
            List<UnidadeLaboratorioDTO> listDto = list.stream().map(obj -> new UnidadeLaboratorioDTO(obj))
                    .collect(Collectors.toList());
            return ResponseEntity.ok().body(listDto);
        }

        @RequestMapping(value = "/page", method = RequestMethod.GET)
        public ResponseEntity<Page<UnidadeLaboratorioDTO>> findPage( // page?page=XXX&linesPerPage=XXX&orderBy=XXX&direction=XXX
                @RequestParam(value = "page", defaultValue = "0") Integer page,
                @RequestParam(value = "linesPerPage", defaultValue = "24") Integer linesPerPage,
                @RequestParam(value = "orderBy", defaultValue = "laboratorio") String orderBy,
                @RequestParam(value = "direction", defaultValue = "ASC") String direction) {
            Page<UnidadeLaboratorio> list = service.findPage(page, linesPerPage, orderBy, direction);
            Page<UnidadeLaboratorioDTO> listDto = list.map(obj -> new UnidadeLaboratorioDTO(obj));
            return ResponseEntity.ok().body(listDto);
        }

        @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST)
        public ResponseEntity<Void> insert(@Valid @RequestBody UnidadeLaboratorioNewDTO objDto) {
            UnidadeLaboratorio obj = service.fromNewDTO(objDto);
            obj = service.insert(obj);
            URI uri = ServletUriComponentsBuilder.fromCurrentRequest().path("/{id}")
                    .buildAndExpand(obj.getId_UnidadeLaboratorio()).toUri();
            return ResponseEntity.created(uri).build();
        }

        @RequestMapping(value = "/{id}", method = RequestMethod.PUT)
        public ResponseEntity<Void> update(@PathVariable Integer id, @Valid @RequestBody UnidadeLaboratorioDTO objDto) {
            UnidadeLaboratorio obj = service.fromDTO(objDto);
            obj.setId_UnidadeLaboratorio(id);
            obj = service.update(obj);
            return ResponseEntity.noContent().build();
        }

        @RequestMapping(value = "/{id}", method = RequestMethod.DELETE)
        public ResponseEntity<Void> delete(@PathVariable Integer id) {
            service.delete(id);
            return ResponseEntity.noContent().build();
        }

    }
```

ExameResource.java

```
    package com.moliveiralucas.easylab.resources;

    import java.net.URI;
    import java.util.List;
    import java.util.stream.Collectors;

    import javax.validation.Valid;

    import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
    import org.springframework.data.domain.Page;
    import org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity;
    import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PathVariable;
    import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestBody;
    import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
    import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
    import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestParam;
    import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;
    import org.springframework.web.servlet.support.ServletUriComponentsBuilder;

    import com.moliveiralucas.easylab.domain.Exame;
    import com.moliveiralucas.easylab.dto.ExameDTO;
    import com.moliveiralucas.easylab.services.ExameService;

    @RestController
    @RequestMapping(value = "/exames")
    public class ExameResource {

        @Autowired
        private ExameService service;

        @RequestMapping(value = "/{id}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
        public ResponseEntity<?> find(@PathVariable Integer id) {
            Exame obj = service.find(id);
            return ResponseEntity.ok().body(obj);
        }

        @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET)
        public ResponseEntity<List<ExameDTO>> findAll() {
            List<Exame> list = service.findAll();
            List<ExameDTO> listDto = list.stream().map(obj -> new ExameDTO(obj)).collect(Collectors.toList());
            return ResponseEntity.ok().body(listDto);
        }

        @RequestMapping(value = "/page", method = RequestMethod.GET)
        public ResponseEntity<Page<ExameDTO>> findPage( // page?page=XXXX&linesPerPage=XXXX&orderBy=XXXX&direction=XXXX
                @RequestParam(value = "page", defaultValue = "0") Integer page,
                @RequestParam(value = "linesPerPage", defaultValue = "24") Integer linesPerPage,
                @RequestParam(value = "orderBy", defaultValue = "exame") String orderBy,
                @RequestParam(value = "direction", defaultValue = "ASC") String direction) {
            Page<Exame> list = service.findPage(page, linesPerPage, orderBy, direction);
            Page<ExameDTO> listDto = list.map(obj -> new ExameDTO(obj));
            return ResponseEntity.ok().body(listDto);
        }

        @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST)
        public ResponseEntity<Void> insert(@Valid @RequestBody ExameDTO objDto) {
            Exame obj = service.fromDTO(objDto);
            obj = service.insert(obj);
            URI uri = ServletUriComponentsBuilder.fromCurrentRequest().path("/{id}").buildAndExpand(obj.getId_Exame())
                    .toUri();
            return ResponseEntity.created(uri).build();
        }

        @RequestMapping(value = "/{id}", method = RequestMethod.PUT)
        public ResponseEntity<Void> update(@PathVariable Integer id, @Valid @RequestBody ExameDTO objDto) {
            Exame obj = service.fromDTO(objDto);
            obj.setId_Exame(id);
            obj = service.update(obj);
            return ResponseEntity.noContent().build();
        }

        @RequestMapping(value = "/{id}", method = RequestMethod.DELETE)
        public ResponseEntity<Void> delete(@PathVariable Integer id) {
            service.delete(id);
            return ResponseEntity.noContent().build();
        }

    }
```

## Classes de Serviço

UnidadeLaboratorioService.java

```
    package com.moliveiralucas.easylab.services;

    import java.util.List;
    import java.util.Optional;

    import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
    import org.springframework.dao.DataIntegrityViolationException;
    import org.springframework.data.domain.Page;
    import org.springframework.data.domain.PageRequest;
    import org.springframework.data.domain.Sort.Direction;
    import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;
    import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional;

    import com.moliveiralucas.easylab.domain.Cidade;
    import com.moliveiralucas.easylab.domain.Laboratorio;
    import com.moliveiralucas.easylab.domain.UnidadeLaboratorio;
    import com.moliveiralucas.easylab.dto.UnidadeLaboratorioDTO;
    import com.moliveiralucas.easylab.dto.UnidadeLaboratorioNewDTO;
    import com.moliveiralucas.easylab.repositories.UnidadeLaboratorioRepository;
    import com.moliveiralucas.easylab.services.exceptions.DataIntegrityException;
    import com.moliveiralucas.easylab.services.exceptions.ObjectNotFoundException;

    @Service
    public class UnidadeLaboratorioService {

        @Autowired
        private UnidadeLaboratorioRepository repo;

        public UnidadeLaboratorio find(Integer id) {
            Optional<UnidadeLaboratorio> obj = repo.findById(id);
            return obj.orElseThrow(() -> new ObjectNotFoundException(
                    "Objeto não encontrado! ID: " + id + ", Tipo: " + UnidadeLaboratorio.class.getName()));
        }

        public List<UnidadeLaboratorio> findAll() {
            return repo.findAll();
        }

        public Page<UnidadeLaboratorio> findPage(Integer page, Integer linesPerPage, String orderBy, String direction) {
            PageRequest pageRequest = PageRequest.of(page, linesPerPage, Direction.valueOf(direction), orderBy);
            return repo.findAll(pageRequest);
        }

        @Transactional
        public UnidadeLaboratorio insert(UnidadeLaboratorio obj) {
            obj.setId_UnidadeLaboratorio(null);
            return repo.save(obj);
        }

        public UnidadeLaboratorio update(UnidadeLaboratorio obj) {
            UnidadeLaboratorio newObj = find(obj.getId_UnidadeLaboratorio());
            updateData(newObj, obj);
            return repo.save(newObj);
        }

        private void updateData(UnidadeLaboratorio newObj, UnidadeLaboratorio obj) {
            newObj.setNomeUnidade(obj.getNomeUnidade());
            newObj.setLogradouro(obj.getLogradouro());
            newObj.setComplemento(obj.getComplemento());
            newObj.setNumero(obj.getNumero());
            newObj.setTelefone(obj.getTelefone());
        }

        public void delete(Integer id) {
            find(id);
            try {
                repo.deleteById(id);
            } catch (DataIntegrityViolationException e) {
                throw new DataIntegrityException("Não é possível excluir!");
            }
        }

        public UnidadeLaboratorio fromDTO(UnidadeLaboratorioDTO objDto) {
            return new UnidadeLaboratorio(objDto.getId_UnidadeLaboratorio(), objDto.getNomeUnidade(),
                    objDto.getLogradouro(), objDto.getComplemento(), objDto.getNumero(), objDto.getTelefone(), null, null);
        }

        public UnidadeLaboratorio fromNewDTO(UnidadeLaboratorioNewDTO objDto) {
            Laboratorio laboratorio = new Laboratorio(objDto.getId_Laboratorio(), null, null, null);
            Cidade cidade = new Cidade(objDto.getId_Cidade(), null, null);
            UnidadeLaboratorio unidadeLaboratorio = new UnidadeLaboratorio(null, objDto.getNomeUnidade(),
                    objDto.getLogradouro(), objDto.getComplemento(), objDto.getNumero(), objDto.getTelefone(), cidade,
                    laboratorio);
            laboratorio.getUnidades().add(unidadeLaboratorio);
            return unidadeLaboratorio;
        }
    }
```

ExameService.java

```
    package com.moliveiralucas.easylab.services;

    import java.util.List;
    import java.util.Optional;

    import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
    import org.springframework.dao.DataIntegrityViolationException;
    import org.springframework.data.domain.Page;
    import org.springframework.data.domain.PageRequest;
    import org.springframework.data.domain.Sort.Direction;
    import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

    import com.moliveiralucas.easylab.domain.Exame;
    import com.moliveiralucas.easylab.dto.ExameDTO;
    import com.moliveiralucas.easylab.repositories.ExameRepository;
    import com.moliveiralucas.easylab.services.exceptions.DataIntegrityException;
    import com.moliveiralucas.easylab.services.exceptions.ObjectNotFoundException;

    @Service
    public class ExameService {

        @Autowired
        private ExameRepository repo;

        public Exame find(Integer id) {
            Optional<Exame> obj = repo.findById(id);
            return obj.orElseThrow(() -> new ObjectNotFoundException(
                    "Objeto não encontrado! ID: " + id + ", Tipo: " + Exame.class.getName()));
        }

        public List<Exame> findAll() {
            return repo.findAll();
        }

        public Page<Exame> findPage(Integer page, Integer linesPerPage, String orderBy, String direction) {
            PageRequest pageRequest = PageRequest.of(page, linesPerPage, Direction.valueOf(direction), orderBy);
            return repo.findAll(pageRequest);
        }

        public Exame insert(Exame obj) {
            obj.setId_Exame(null);
            return repo.save(obj);
        }

        public Exame update(Exame obj) {
            Exame newObj = find(obj.getId_Exame());
            updateData(newObj, obj);
            return repo.save(newObj);
        }

        private void updateData(Exame newObj, Exame obj) {
            newObj.setExame(obj.getExame());
            newObj.setSigla(obj.getSigla());
        }

        public void delete(Integer id) {
            find(id);
            try {
                repo.deleteById(id);
            } catch (DataIntegrityViolationException e) {
                throw new DataIntegrityException("Não é possível excluir!");
            }
        }

        public Exame fromDTO(ExameDTO objDto) {
            return new Exame(objDto.getId_Exame(), objDto.getExame(), objDto.getSigla());
        }

    }
```

Estas são as classes que estou utilizando para fazer manter os exames e as unidades, a que fica minha duvida é, devo criar uma nova classe para manter/mapear esse relacionamento entre unidadeLaboratorio e exame para que eu possa manipular os dados nele ou devo só fazer um método responsável para tal coisa.

O repositório no qual o projeto inteiro está armazenado é: [Github](https://github.com/moliveiralucas/EasyLab/tree/master/server/EasyLabWebService)

Desde ja agradeço a colaboração de todos :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> devo criar uma nova classe para manter/mapear esse relacionamento entre unidadeLaboratorio e exame para que eu possa manipular os dados nele

Sim, creio que vai precisar fazer isto. Como o relacionamento entre eles é de muitos para muitos (`@ManyToMany`), você precisa de uma tabela intermediária para amarrar os identificadores das tabelas de `unidadeLaboratorio` e `exame`, uma tabela `unidadeLaboratorio_exame`. Exemplo:

```
unidadeLaboratorio_id | exame_id
1                     | 10
2                     | 11
2                     | 10
```

Para facilitar, normalmente inclui um ID nesta tabela também. Assim, o mapeamento seria algo como:

```
@Entity
class UnidadeLaboratorioExame {

    @Id
    private Long id;

    @ManyToOne
    private Exame exame;

    @ManyToOne
    private UnidadeLaboratorio unidade;

}
```

E nas entidade `UnidadeLaboratorio` e `Exame`, o relacionamento com `UnidadeLaboratorioExame` é `@OneToMany`. A ideia aqui é não usar `@ManyToMany` e você ter o controle desta tabela, ficando mapeada na sua aplicação.

Comment: Sim estive pensando nessa solução, o JPA já cria essa tabela do resultado N para N porém eu não consigo manipular os dados nela, eu n tenho uma entidade mapeada para receber os atributos, e criando uma nova classe fica mais fácil para futuras atualizações, tais como adicionar preço ao exame e coisas do tipo, mas obrigado pela ajuda

Comment: Estou complementando! A ideia é não usar ManyToMany. Espere 2 minutos que já complemento